# instance variables for allocated cocoa subclassed objects

Tags: cocoa, variables, object, instance

I have tried a very large number of variations of declaring a couple of long variables for a subclass of NSButton; basically, when the object is created, I want to stick a couple of values in there so my programattically created buttons will work...

```
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
...
scbi = [[[MyNSButtonSubClass alloc] initWithFrame: buttonInitRect] 
                             autorelease];
[scbi setButtonid: myLongButtonId];
[scbi setTarget: self];
[scbi setAction: @selector(buttonAction:];
...
[pool release];
```

will work with this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    MyNSButtonSubclass *snbi;
    long buttonid;
    snbi = (MyNSButtonSubclass *)sender
    buttonid = [snbi buttonid];
}
```

in the subclass, I have:

```
- (void)setButtonid:(long)x
{
    buttonid = x;
}
```

...I've tried declaring the buttonid long in the global scope and in the interface structure in the header file, I've tried using properties, removed the setter and getter and tried @synthesize... and I've checked the set calls, they are receiving the various long ids... but no matter what I do, the buttonAction method gets back zeros from [snbi buttonid]; no matter which button is pressed (there can be hundreds, and the number varies. I have to know which button was pressed, and I can't write a separate target routine for them, because I don't know how many there will be at any one time.)

It appears that the need for adding instance variables to a subclass is be so obvious, and the mechanism to access them so basic, that no one ever talks about it. I can't find anything about it that leads to working code. The Cocoa docs mention it, but don't demonstrate it, or at least that I could find.

Any insight, anyone?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem. Using a synthesized `buttonID` property in the `NSButton` subclass, and adding the step (which I assume you're doing, but which you've left out) of adding the button to a view, I can get the `buttonID` value inside `buttonAction`. By the way, why are you creating your own NSAutoreleasePool?

Comment: Josh, thanks for trying. When you say "using a synthesized buttonID property", can you lay out the code? @synthesize buttonID; in the implementation, right? And then where do the actual variables go? These are longs, not objects, btw. Really appreciate the help. Autorelease.... book said I should. :)

Comment: @fyngyrz: Instance variables go inside the braces of the class definition (e.g. `@interface Foo : NSObject { IVARS GO HERE }`) — always, no matter what type they are. If you are not clear about how to define a class, I strongly recommend you read Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language": http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: Chuck, that's exactly where they are (inside the structure braces.) The point is, it **doesn't work**, and that's why I was asking. So that part is right.

Comment: Oh, good grief. It was a copy/paste error. Subtle, but still. Never mind, thanks for your time. Works fine.

Comment: So you've solved it? Glad if you did! You might take a minute to type up a formal answer, so the question doesn't languish in "Unanswered". Re: AutoreleasePool, calling `autorelease` on the buttons is correct, but I don't see any reason why you need to create your own pool. If you're dealing with the GUI, you must be on the main thread, and therefore there is automatically an autorelease pool you can already use. Perhaps the book was just demonstrating the concept of creating your own. /shrug

Comment: If you are subclassing just to add a *button id* ivar, I'd suggest you have a look at the `tag` property of UIView.